# 'No qualifying bean of type' in a web application Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a web application in spring boot  and I am facing this error it can't find the bean 'MedecinDao' nevertheless I added @component in MedecinDao
and for medecinDao it's an interface
can anyone helps me ?

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'dreamHospital.Dao.MedecinRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at com.DreamHospital.DreamHospital.DreamHospitalApplication.main(DreamHospitalApplication.java:23
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DreamHospitalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context= SpringApplication.run(DreamHospitalApplication.class, args);


        MedecinDao MD  = context.getBean(MedecinDao.class);
        medecin M1 = new medecin("Azzedine RIHANE","Dermatologiste");
        medecin M2 = new medecin("Riadh Bouftira","Médecin de famille");
        medecin M3 = new medecin("Khaled Machraoui","Médecin de famille");
        medecin M4 = new medecin("Mohamed Moalla","Rhumatologue");
        medecin M5 = new medecin("Abderrazek Mnif","Urologue");
        medecin M6 = new medecin("ghezel slim","Dermatologiste");
        medecin M7 = new medecin("Mounir Makni","Gynécologue");
```

```
@Component
public interface MedecinDao extends JpaRepository<medecin, UUID>{

    List<medecin> findAll();
    List<medecin> findBySpecialite(String specialite);

    List<medecin> findByPatients(patient patient);

    @Override
    default Optional<medecin> findById(UUID id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Query("select patients from medecin m where m.idM like : x")
    List<patient> findPatients(@Param("x")UUID idM);

    @Override
    default void deleteById(UUID id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code as code, not as image. Read the FAQ and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about jpa and springboot. Springboot automatic creates beans on JPA Repositories which are present in the same or nested packages of Main Application.
Your main App i.e `DreamHospitalApplication` is present in `com.DreamHospital.DreamHospital` packages whereas
`MedecinDao` is present in `dreamHospital.Dao.MedecinRepository`.

It seems like you are a beginner, you should keep all your repository packages inside main app package. There are other possible ways also like using annotation `EnableJpaRepositories` on Main class, that you can learn with time.